# Discord Bot Status FiveM

Tags: javascript

This is my code and i have error like this

```
/home/bot/index.js:37 let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount; ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'memberCount' of undefined at fivereborn.query (/home/bot/index.js:37:35) at Socket.client.on (/home/bot/node_modules/fivereborn-query/index.js:58:5) at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) at Socket.emit (events.js:214:7) at UDP.onMessage [as onmessage] (dgram.js:659:8)
```

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const configs = require("./configs.json");
const fivereborn = require('fivereborn-query');
client.config = configs;

client.login(configs.token).then(() => {
    console.log("status started!");
    console.log("Receiving information, please wait...");
}, () => {
    client.destroy();
    console.log("Bot destroyed!");
});

function refresh() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fivereborn.query(configs.serverInfo[0], configs.serverInfo[1], (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                let myGuild = client.guilds.get('811672555022057512');
                let memberCount = myGuild.memberCount;
                let memberCountChannel = myGuild.channels.get('816581139682426881');
                memberCountChannel.setName(" Online: " + data.clients + "/" + data.maxclients);
            }
        });
        refresh();
    }, 10000);
}
refresh();

function activity() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fivereborn.query(configs.serverInfo[0], configs.serverInfo[1], (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                client.user.setActivity("Online: " + data.clients + "/" + data.maxclients, {
                    type: configs.activityType
                });
            }
        });
        activity();
    }, 10000);
}
activity();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get guild and channel by `.get` you have to use cache.
Just change the `let myGuild = client.guilds.get('811672555022057512');` to
`let myGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('811672555022057512');` do the same with the `channels.get` and add .cache (`channels.cache.get(id)`)

The `cache` is the collection ([https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache)) and there you have the function get.

You can also use the `.fetch`, check this [https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=cache)